# Why can't I access my gitlab service postgres database?

Tags: postgresql, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I want to establish a gitlab test stage that uses a gitlab service postgres database. The problem is, that everytime I try to access the database via a script call in the pipeline I get the following error:

```bash
psql: error: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "postgres" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

yaml looks the following

```yaml
image: some_image:latest

stages:
    - test

tests:
    image: node:latest
    stage: test
    services:
        - postgres:latest
    before_script:
        - apt-get update && apt-get install -y postgresql-client libpq-dev
        # access database script from another repo here through git clone
        - psql -U postgres -h postgres < ./create-database.sql
    script:
        - npm install
        - npm run tests
    only:
        - master
```

Am I missing something - is the database maybe not created and I am calling to soon?

Comment: How is your DB configured? SHould be done at this file since UI params are not passed to the DB container.
Check the docs here and add `VARIABLES` https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/postgres.html

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick - should have read the documentation. ;) Can you please put this into an actual answer so I can accept it for your reputation gain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the configuration properties of the DB. They can not be configured on the UI - or they can but won't be passed to the actual DB service.
So please add the following properties to the script:

```
variables:
  POSTGRES_DB: <db name>
  POSTGRES_USER: <db user>
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: <some PW>
  POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
```

Documentation link: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/postgres.html